# Telephone pad not visible in Gmail

Tags: google-talk

When I sign on to Gmail, there's no longer a way to acces the telephone feature. The word "chat" has disappeared! What can I do to access Gmail Chat again?

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure chat is on. For this, go to Settings → Chat → Select **Chat on** → Click **Save Changes** at the bottom of the page. Second, if you are using the "new" Gmail, make sure the chat widget is visible. There is a small "square bubble" in the bottom-left corner of the Gmail window, that hides/unhides the widget (see photo below—in "hide" state)—make sure it's unhidden.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your settings. Go to Gear/Mail Settings/Chat The first item turns chat on or off.